# Exchanging Series with Integrals: when is it possible?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals

In what cases is it possible to exchange between Series and Integral signs, namely performing the following operation?

$$\sum\int F(x) \text{d}x ~~~~~ \to ~~~~~ \int\sum F(x) \text{d}x$$

What are the sufficient / necessary conditions? I know it might be a hard work to write here the inherent theory but it would really help me to understand once for all that question.

Comment: If the sum is finite then it is possible always. If the sum is an infinite sum then you are looking for uniform convergence http://www.math.ku.edu/~lerner/m500f09/Uniform%20Convergence.pdf

Comment: Note that by linearity, it's always possible to do this for finite sums. For infinite sums, it becomes a matter of exchanging a limit and an integral which you can use Fubini's convergence theorem, monotone convergence theorem, Vitali's convergence theorem, etc.

Comment: Well yes, my problem was clearly understood for infinite series. I will check the last convergence theorem then! I know them but Vitali's one!

Comment: Uniform convergence, while sufficient, is not necessary. For example if $F(x)$ is always nonnegative then we can exchange the sum and the integral. We can also do it if all partial sums are bounded by an integrable function (these two results are for the Lebesgue integral).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a general manner, consider $\big( f_n \big)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a series of continuous functions such that $f_n \to f$ [uniformly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence) in a compact interval $[a,b]$ . In your example, 
\begin{equation}
f_n = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n F_n(x)
\end{equation} 
represent the partial sums with $f_n(x) \to \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{\infty} F_n (x) = F(x)$.

We want to prove that: 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty } \int\limits_{a}^{b} f_n(x) dx = \int\limits_{a}^{b} \lim_{n \to \infty }  f_n (x) dx = \int\limits_{a}^{b}  f (x) dx
\end{equation}

**Proof**
We will show that for all $\epsilon > 0 $ exists $N \gg 0$ such that: 
\begin{equation}
\left|\int\limits_{a}^{b}  f (x) dx -  \int\limits_{a}^{b}  f_N (x) dx \right| < \epsilon. 
\end{equation}

Notice that: 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\left|\int\limits_{a}^{b}  f (x) dx -  \int\limits_{a}^{b}  f_N (x) dx \right| \leq \int\limits_{a}^{b} \left|f_N(x) - f(x) \right| dx
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Because $f_n$ is uniformly convergent, there exists $N$ such that $|f_N(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon_1 $ Therefore:

\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{a}^{b} \left|f_N(x) - f(x) \right| dx < \int\limits_{a}^{b} \epsilon_1 = (b-a)\epsilon_1 , \quad \forall x \in [a,b].
\end{equation}

By making $\epsilon_1 = \epsilon /(b-a)$ we obtain that:

\begin{equation}
\left|\int\limits_{a}^{b}  f (x) dx -  \int\limits_{a}^{b}  f_N (x) dx \right| < \epsilon. 
\end{equation}

This proves the theorem.

Comment: This could be considered as a much too restricted setting (at least since the beginning of the XXth century, when Lebesgue, Borel and all the others kind of get interested in the matter...).

Comment: *Typo: got interested.

Comment: Of course it is very restricting. I think the best approach would be using the [Henstock-Kurzweil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral) integral (as it includes Lebesgue's and improper Riemann's integrals) but I thought the OP was asking from an Introduction to Calculus viewpoint...

Comment: The most common approach, by far, is à la Lebesgue.